# TypeScript Type Conditionals

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Given an abstract Class with three type parameters `Model`, `DTO` and `DomainEntity`.

```js
export abstract class AbstractBaseDataMapper<Model, DTO extends BaseDTO, DomainEntity extends BaseDomainEntity> {
    public abstract toDomain(t: Model | Model[] | null): Promise<DomainEntity | DomainEntity[] | null>;
    public abstract toPersistence(t: DomainEntity): Promise<any>;
    public abstract toDTO(t: DomainEntity | DomainEntity[] | null): Promise<DTO | DTO[] | null>;

    public dateToString<T extends Date | null>(date: T): StringOrUndefined<T> {
        throw "unimplemented";
    }
}
```

What I want is to extend every `DTO` and `DomainEntity` with its Base-Class but just for those which are really relevant e.g. having the necessary fields in database.
So I need to type the 2nd and 3rd Parameter conditinally (I guess :-))
I am pretty much stuck at how to type the the extension on the true-branche. Any other suggestions are appreciated as well for sure

I thought about something like that

```js
type A<B> = B & BaseDomainEntity;
type DomainEntityOrExtended<T extends BaseDomainEntity> = T extends BaseDomainEntity ? A<T> : T;
type Asdf<T extends BaseDomainEntity> = DomainEntityOrExtended<T>;

abstract class AbstractBaseDataMapper<Model, DTO extends BaseDTO, DomainEntity extends BaseDomainEntity = Asdf<DomainEntity>> {}
```

But that doesn't work. Hope someone can enlight me :-)

Edit:

I've added some more declarations to be more clear. [TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N72YBw)

Comment: Your code is [missing a lot of definitions](https://tsplay.dev/N9bRJm), which makes it harder to help and even discourages from doing so.

Comment: @vera. I've added some more definitions on that.

Comment: • Could you pare that code down to be a [mre]? In my experience most issues can be demonstrated in a single screenful of code without needing scrolling. Any property/method/comment/definition that isn't necessary to show the problem should be removed. • Could you make sure that your problem is clear from the code? Saying "that doesn't work" isn't sufficient. • Also, please include the code as plain text; a playground link is a great supplement but we can't require people navigate away from SO to see the relevant code.  • Good luck!